# How to receive an SMS and then process it with your filtering mechanism to transfer it to the PC

Tags: java-me, sms

The following steps show the communication protocol between the Mobile application and the server application:

1. The user (phone number +123456789) sends an SMS message to the Mobile, e.g. "VOTE A 987-65-4329." The message format is: VOTE `<Choice> <Social Security Number>`.
2. The Mobile receives the message from the user and forwards it to the server application along with the phone number. The server receives the SMS message and tallies the vote count. The communication between the Mobile and the server is conducted over a Bluetooth connection.
3. The server sends a command "SEND:+123456789:Thank you for your vote!" to the Mobile application.
4. The Mobile receives the command from server and sends an SMS message "Thank you for your vote!" to the phone number +123456789.

Any idea about the mobile app that how it filter the message & forward it to th PC in j2me.
Thanx in advanc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is completely possible!

Please refer to my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846634/sending-sms-using-java-me-application).